# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. HTTP Status 400 -

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have so method signature in my @Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/saveCandidate")
        public String saveCandidate(Model model,
                @ModelAttribute("candidateFromRequest") Candidate candidateFromRequest,
                @ModelAttribute("skillsIdList") Set<Skill> skills,
                @ModelAttribute("vacanciesForCandidate") Set<Vacancy> vacanciesForCandidate)
```

and  so form:

```
<form action="saveCandidate"  id="formId" method="POST">
....
<input type="submit" value="save changes"/>
</form>
```

In debug I see, that all @ModelAttribute Entities put on request.

Why as a result I see

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. HTTP
>   Status 400 -

in my browser

code:

```
@ModelAttribute(value = "candidateFromRequest")
    public Candidate loadCandidateById(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer id) {
        if (id!= null)
            return candidateService.findById(id);
        return null;
    }

@ModelAttribute(value = "skillsIdList")
    public Set<Skill> getSkillListById(@RequestParam(required = false) List<Integer> skills,@ModelAttribute("skills")List<Skill> allSkills ) {
        if (skills== null)
            return null;
        Set<Skill> returnList = new  HashSet<Skill>();
        for(Integer skillId:skills){
            for(Skill skill:allSkills){
                if(skillId.equals(skill.getId())){
                    returnList.add(skill);
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }
        return returnList;
    }

@ModelAttribute(value = "vacanciesForCandidate")
public Set<Vacancy> vacanciesForCandidate(@RequestParam(required = false) 

List<Integer> vacancies,@ModelAttribute("vacancies")List<Vacancy> allVacancies ) {
        if (vacancies== null)
            return null;
        Set<Vacancy> returnList = new  HashSet<Vacancy>();
        for(Integer vacancyId:vacancies){
            for(Vacancy vacancy:allVacancies){
                if(vacancyId.equals(vacancy.getId())){
                    returnList.add(vacancy);
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

In debug I saw, that methods, writes above return valid values.

I replace mehod for GET and saw browser request:

```
http://localhost:8080/ui/saveCandidate?name=Evgeniy&surname=Rogachev&phone=02&resumeUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&id=1013&skills=2&skills=3&skills=4&skills=5&skills=6&skills=7&skills=8&vacancies=6&vacancies=12&vacancies=14
```

Comment: have u checked the raw http request?

Comment: No, it enow hardly http request, But I can write here what request generates browser